# Java: Set iconimage without using full path

Tags: java, image, path, imageicon

I'm creating a game in java, and I have some problems setting my icon image:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("/Users/me/location/mygame/res/logo.png");
f.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

This works fine, but instead of **/Users/me/location/mygame/res/logo.png**, I want **/logo.png**, as I do with all images except this one.

Example of a place when it works perfectly:

```
player_sheet = loader.loadImage("/player_sheet.png");
```

This example is from my Texture class.

If I put **/logo.png** in the path, there will be no icon at all.

Comment: You’ll want to do some research into “embedded resources” - essentially, you include the images (and other resources) in the packaged jar and load them using a `Class#getResource`

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way to do that? If not, how do I do this?

Comment: That would depend on your ide and build system